# R Cluster Analysis

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I was following the code listed below from https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html

```
library(cluster)   
d <- dist(t(dtmss), method="euclidian")   
fit <- hclust(d=d, method="ward")   
fit

plot.new()
plot(fit, hang=-1)
groups <- cutree(fit, k=5) 
rect.hclust(fit, k=5, border="red")
```

How can I print the words in each cluster? The dendrogram gets very cramped and is completely unreadable.

Thank you!

EDITS:

For input, consider any csv file with a column named "Comment". Every observation (50 rows) has text comments.

I then used the code from the link above:

```
library(tm)

input = read.csv("FILEPATH/InputFile.csv")
summary(input)

comments <- Corpus(VectorSource(input$Comment))

data <- tm_map(comments, removePunctuation)
data <- tm_map(data, removeNumbers)
data <- tm_map(data, tolower)
data <- tm_map(data, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
data <- tm_map(data, PlainTextDocument)

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(data)
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
ord <- order(freq)
findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq = 10)
freq <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing = TRUE)
head(freq, 30)

dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.1) 
inspect(dtms)

library(cluster)   
d <- dist(t(dtms), method="euclidian")   
fit <- hclust(d=d, method="ward")   
fit   
plot(fit, hang=-1)   

plot.new()
plot(fit, hang=-1)
groups <- cutree(fit, k=5)  
rect.hclust(fit, k=5, border="red")
```

I hope this is enough information.

Thanks again.

Comment: The example, as you've presented it here, is not reproducible. I think there's more code and data you'll need to include in the question from your tutorial to meet the MCVE requirement.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to reproduce it with the iris dataset...

Comment: @stata00 That edit helps a lot. It's just missing the actual input file, I think. Is there a link to the .csv on that tutorial that you can include?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I created a random csv file on my PC. Would you like me to find some example online and post the link for that? My apologies for any inconvenience.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-spss-survey-text-mining1/#download has example data. Please change the column name in the code from "$Comment" to the name of the comments column in the sample data and that should work. I hope it makes it easier to run the code now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cluster the observation is in from the groups and then subset your data based on them:

```
t(dtms)[groups==1]
```

that should print out members of cluster 1.

Comment: I tried it. I am getting the error "Error in x$nrow : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

Comment: what is the structure of the dtmss? dtmss$nrow will try to access a variable (column) called nrow in the dataset. Maybe you want something like dtmss[1:nrow,]?

Comment: Made an edit to my post. I have included code for the full example. Thanks!